# Azure Function REST API PUT returns 202

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a REST API built in an Azure function. My PUT endpoints are returning the 202 async pattern, but all other endpoints are returning 200s.

This returns a 200 after updating the user's profile image

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutProfileImage(
          [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "profileimage")] HttpRequest req,
          ILogger log)
```

This returns a 202 Accepted and never completes

```
        [FunctionName("PutProfileImage")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutProfileImage(
          [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "put", Route = "profileimage")] HttpRequest req,
          ILogger log)
```

Windows 10, VS 2019 16.9.4, Azure Functions V3, .NET Core 3.1. Happy to gather any more info that might help to understand this behavior.

Update 5/8/2021
This is a known issue being tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1878 and here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7260

Comment: Would be great to see what you are returning for ```PutProfileImage()```

Comment: Can you show more code? On my side it can complete.

Comment: Do your ```"put"``` have ```await``` keyword for async function call?

Comment: This is the return `return new OkObjectResult(result.Resource.Id);`. It's just returning the objectId that was edited. They are the exact same function. It's why I didn't show all the code. I literally just change the verb from PUT to POST and works as expected.

Comment: You say you have a REST API built in an Azure function. Can you post this code? If no code in the function body, use put method will be no problem.

Comment: This is a known issue being tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1878 and here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7260

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds this, it's a known issue in the Azure Functions runtime. The issue being tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1878 and here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7260